# Form method post and jquery/javascript code dosnt work on 1 single computer in all browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-core

I have a website coded in asp.net core 2.1. In one of the razor views I have 2 `<input type="date">`(a startdate and an enddate), a `submit` button and some jquery/javascript code (to check that the enddate isn't before the startdate and the startdate isn't after current date and startdate isn't after enddate). This is all working in all browsers and on all computers as it should, EXCEPT ON 1 single computer.

The system that isnt working is running Windows 10 pro x64, and everything should be updated.

The exact same setup is on another laptop where it IS WORKING.
Both laptops are part of same company so they are identical in manufacturer, OS and software. None of them are part of a Domain.

The page loads really fast, as if it was cached, but I cleared all browser data, and updates on code and html tags is displaying. I cant seem to pinpoint the problem. This is what I tried so far:

- I tried on other computers on all browsers with the exact same setup (as far as I know
- I tried Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer and Edge. Same result
- I tried clearing browser data (everything)

***UPDATE****
I tried changing the default input date to Jquery datepicker. The same error persists. It defaults to 01 january 1901. Works everywhere else. 
This is only happening on 1 single computer :-(
Picture of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT7ol.jpg
***UPDATE***

This is my code:
HTML/Razor view

```
 <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Fra dato</label></td>
                <td><label>Til dato</label></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="date" id="TB_StartDate" name="TB_StartDate" required value="@ViewBag.StartDate" /></td>
                <td><input type="date" id="TB_EndDate" name="TB_EndDate" required value="@ViewBag.EndDate" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="BTN_ReloadDates" class="btn btn-primary" value="Hent ændringer" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <label class="label label-danger" style="font-size: large;" for="Datepick" id="L_Warning"></label>
```

JQuery

```
<script src="~/js/Jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#L_Warning").hide();


    $('#TB_StartDate').change(function () {
        $("#L_Warning").hide();
        var StartDate = $("#TB_StartDate").val();
        var EndDate = $("#TB_EndDate").val();
        var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        if (StartDate > now) {
            $("#TB_StartDate").val(now);
            $("#TB_EndDate").val(now);
            $("#L_Warning").show();
            $("#L_Warning").fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn();

            $("#L_Warning").text("Du kan ikke vælge en nyere dato end idag.");

        }
        else if (StartDate > EndDate) {
            $("#TB_EndDate").val(StartDate);
        }


    });

    $('#TB_EndDate').change(function () {
        $("#L_Warning").hide();
        var StartDate = $("#TB_StartDate").val();
        var EndDate = $("#TB_EndDate").val();
        var now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        if (EndDate > now) {
            $("#TB_EndDate").val(now);
            $("#L_Warning").show();
            $("#L_Warning").fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn();

            $("#L_Warning").text("Du kan ikke vælge en nyere dato end idag.");

        }
        else if (EndDate < StartDate) {
            $("#TB_StartDate").val(EndDate);
        }


    });


</script>
```

Comment: You need to publish and run setup.exe on deploy computer.  Visual Studio applications only work in the same version of Net is installed on Build and Deploy computers.  Running Setup.exe resolves differences in windows dlls used by Net.  Also make sure you build using AnyPC (also x86 if necessary).

Comment: The website works on ALL other computers except this one. The problem is localised to the computer somehow. the webserver isnt the problem ;-)

Comment: I didn't say anything about the webserver.  Where are you running the client?  It is possible the  java settings in your IE is setup different or different version of java.

Comment: @jdweng - I don't see any mention of Java

Comment: @JohnnyBjerring - Can you describe more about how you are testing this? Is the website running on each computer and being accessed via localhost? Or have you deployed/hosting this somewhere and accessing it remotely via browser?

Comment: See title of posting : "Form method post and jquery/javascript code dosnt work on 1 single computer in all browsers"

Comment: @jdweng The client is running Windows 10. Its not just IE. Its all the browsers. The site is not running Java of any kind

Comment: @MarkCooper The website is deployed to a webserver so all the clients are accessing them from the same server on the same address.

Comment: @jdweng - the version of Java that is installed (or not) doesn't have any bearing on JavaScript. That is dependent on the JavaScript engine running in the browser, which will vary between browser and version.

Comment: @JohnnyBjerring - can you add details of this to the question, and then add more details about one of your systems that is working, and the one that is not (O/S, Browser, version). Identifying the differences will lead to the solution :-)

Comment: @MarkCooper I have updated the question ;-) But both systems are running identical setup since they are part of the same company and bought for the same :-)

Comment: @JohnnyBjerring - frustrating problem, but thinking pragmatically - computers don't make mistakes so something MUST be different between the two scenarios. On the computer with the problem; does it work on _any_ browser, or are they all broken?

Comment: @MarkCooper im afraid they are ALL broken :-( I narrowed it down to her browsers reading the <input date> differently. At first, the input revered to empty. No value in the input field at all. I changed the values from viewbag to a datetime string in same format, i got the value 01-01-0001. still not the right value in the boxes.

Comment: @JohnnyBjerring - so if _all_ browsers aren't working, and these browsers are _all_ the same versions as a system that is working, then you've narrowed the problem somewhat... Look next at either system configuration or the network. Can you see any errors in Chrome DevTools? Perhaps some assets or data not downloading?

Comment: @MarkCooper There is no errors in DevTools. That was the first place i looked :-) Both laptops are connecting to the same network at the same hotspot. System config should be the same, but i dont know which things i should check for. The laptop is the same models, bought the same place, but that offcourse is not the same as the same system setup :-) Im trying to change the website today to use Jquery Datepicker instead of standard HTML input tags to see if it makes a difference :-)

Comment: @MarkCooper The problem still exists even though im using Datepicker now. I have added a picture of the problem to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SOLVED IT :-)

Turns out, the problem had something to do with the user on the system.
(I forgot to remove some test code that messed up with that particular user).